# Simple calculator in Java

Tags: java, beginner, calculator

I've been learning Java for about 3 weeks now, and I was hoping someone could check over my code for me, and let me know how to improve.

I am aware that the maths class could be removed (I could've typed `answer = inputA * inputB` etc. within the switch statement) but this is just because I wanted to practice using multiple classes.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    Maths Maths = new Maths();

    double answer = 0;
    double inputA, inputB;
    char operator;
    boolean done = false;

     while (done == false) {
        System.out.print("Please enter your sum: ");

        inputA = input.nextDouble();
        operator = input.next().charAt(0);
        inputB = input.nextDouble();        

        switch (operator) {
            case '+': answer = Maths.add(inputA, inputB);
                      break;
            case '-': answer = Maths.subtract(inputA, inputB);
                      break;
            case '*': answer = Maths.multiply(inputA, inputB);
                      break;
            case '/': answer = Maths.divide(inputA, inputB);
                      break;
            case '^': answer = Maths.power(inputA, inputB);
                      break;
        }

            System.out.println(answer);             
    }       

    input.close();

  }

}
```

And my second class...

```
public class Maths {

    double add(double a, double b) {
        double answer = a+b;
        return answer;          
    }

    double subtract(double a, double b) {
        double answer = a-b;
        return answer;          
    }

    double multiply(double a, double b) {
        double answer = a*b;
        return answer;          
    }

    double divide(double a, double b) {
        double answer = a/b;
        return answer;          
    }

    double power(double a, double b){
        double answer =a;

        for (int x=2; x<=b; x++){
            answer *= a;
        }

        return answer;
    }

}
```

Comment: rhetorical question:  why does java use:  `public static double sqrt(double a)` ?  see the API http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt%28double%29.  hint:  good book, effective java, 2nd edition.  Sometimes methods **should** be static.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For a beginner it's a good approach. You need to know about [Java Naming Convention](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm). We use **mixed case** for naming any variable or instance of a class. So in your code `Maths Maths = new Maths();` should be `Maths maths = new Maths();`.

Or even better make all the methods in `Maths` class `public static` as the instance of the class doesn't play any part in computation. Point to be noted in Java we make utility class's methods static as you can see in API's [Math class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html), [Array class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html).

Suggestions

- In `add`, `subtract` methods you don't need to introduce a new `answer` variable. Just return the result like `return (a+b);` or `return (a-b);`.
- `while (done == false)` is yukkk. Just make it `while (!done)`.

Thumbs up for closing the Scanner. Now read about [Exception handling](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/). Happy programming!!! :D

Comment: Actually, when Scanner is opened to System.in, it should *not* be closed.  You won't be able to use System.in after that.

Comment: @ksnortum Can you explain with an example or any source of this?

Comment: @tintinmj, Here you go: https://gist.github.com/ksnortum/22eeae450122a1112d3e6c1a674359e2

Answer (score 17):

- `power` should probably be using `Math.pow()`.  I'm picturing how slow your code would be at calculating 1.0000001<sup>5000000</sup>.  Or how inaccurate it'll be when someone wants to raise to a non-integer power.  If those are not intended to be allowed, then passing `double`s all over the place seems odd.  But it'd be better to check beforehand and throw an error than return a blatantly incorrect result, in my opinion.
- You never set `done` to true, and thus have an infinite loop; take out the flag and say `while (true)` or `for (;;)`, so that that's apparent.  Don't add the flag back til you're also adding the code that sets it.
- The fact that you use objects doesn't make your code object-oriented.  *How* you use them is what makes the difference.  In this case, you're using classes as namespaces for functions, which is not very object-oriented at all.

  In your case, `Maths` is entirely useless; everything it does would be better done in your own code.  This is an example of gratuitous use of objects.  If you wanted to practice your OOP, you might want to think about how you'd get rid of that `switch` statement.  Hint:

  ```
  public interface BinaryOperation {
      public double resultFor(double left, double right);
  }


  class Multiplication implements BinaryOperation {
      public double resultFor(double left, double right) {
          return left * right;
      }
  }

  class Addition implements BinaryOperation {
      public double resultFor(double left, double right) {
          return left + right;
      }
  }

  private Map<Character, BinaryOperation> operations;

  ...

  operations.put('*', new Multiplication());
  operations.put('+', new Addition());

  ...

  BinaryOperation op = operations.get(operator);
  if (op != null) {
      answer = op.resultFor(inputA, inputB);
  }
  else {
      System.out.println("Error: Unknown operator");
  ]
  ```

Comment: Making a class for just multiplication is overkill. OP is just a beginner, he needs time to know about Map. Give him time to digest :P.

Comment: @tintinmj: He wanted to learn about OOP.  OOP is about more than just saying `new` a lot.  :P  If he's not using polymorphism or encapsulating something, he's not using OOP.  In such cases, he would be better off *not* using it just yet than using it wrong from the very start and getting the wrong ideas ingrained.

Comment: Thanks-- I'll take that on board. As you say, I don't want to get in any bad habits early on